# OpenTK out of bounds issues when trying to build/debug monogame templates and sample code for windowsgl

Tags: visual-studio, monogame, opentk

I am trying to learn Monogame, but any time I try to run even the templates I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in OpenTK.dll

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I have installed Monogame 3.0.1 and OpenTK 1.1 as per this tutorial: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials . I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Here is some output frm trying to run the WindowsGL template:

```
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\matthew\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\GameName2\GameName2\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\GameName2.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x19c4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b0c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1be8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x984) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\matthew\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\GameName2\GameName2\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\GameName2.exe', Symbols loaded.
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\matthew\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\GameName2\GameName2\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\MonoGame.Framework.dll'
'GameName2.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\matthew\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\GameName2\GameName2\bin\WindowsGL\Debug\OpenTK.dll'
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in OpenTK.dll
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
The thread '<No Name>' (0xfc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3160] GameName2.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I also created a virtual 64-bit windows 7 and a 32-bit windows 7 machine on the offending computer and got a similar error concerning opengl32.dll. However, my actual 64-bit Windows 7 box runs the template just fine. What is wrong with my laptop?

I went deeper into the point where the build crashes. I got this log:

```
Call stack with external code
OpenTK.dll!OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinRawKeyboard.GetRegistryKey(string name)
OpenTK.dll!OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinRawKeyboard.RefreshDevices()
OpenTK.dll!OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinRawKeyboard.WinRawKeyboard(System.IntPtr windowHandle)
OpenTK.dll!OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinRawInput.CreateDrivers()
OpenTK.dll!OpenTK.Platform.Windows.WinInputBase.ProcessEvents()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

Once again, this error is only reproducible on a single machine and all the virtual machines used in it.

Comment: The very same problem is happening to me... Windows 8.1 machine, VS 2013 Express, MonoGame 3.0.1. Funny thing is, it doesn't always happen, I have managed to get a sample running, only to later get the IndexOutOfRangeException in OpenTK.dll... Weird...

Comment: The weirdest thing is that I have a Windows 7 box I just tried this on. Works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix in the form of a patched dll via the this steam thread: http://steamcommunity.com/app/218820/discussions/1/864974467282016219/

I replaced the dll in my project folder and in the monogame folder, code runs now. The problem is with the "Virtual Digitizer" on touch enabled systems. OpenTK doesn't know how to handle it, so it crashes. This fix presumably tell OpenTK to ignore devices it doesn't recognize.

Comment: Works just great. Thanks a lot! I wonder if the OpenTK/Monogame teams are aware of the problem, will point them to this question...

Comment: This has been [fixed](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/commit/1b3b510376465136adba1e4e976762426be74260) in [OpenTK 1.1](http://www.opentk.com/news/opentk-1.1-stable-released).

Comment: I can tell you with confidence and frustration that it, in fact, has not.